# Retrieve XML from URL

Tags: android, xml, url

I am having some problems retrieving a xml from url with the following code:

```
    private static String getAlbumArt(String artistName, String albumName){
        try{
        XMLParser xml_parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = xml_parser.getXmlFromUrl(getAlbumURL(artistName, albumName));
        Document doc = xml_parser.getDomElement(xml);
        NodeList N = doc.getElementsByTagName("album");
        Node node = N.item(0);
        NodeList N2 = node.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("1------");
            for (int i = 0; i < N2.getLength(); i++) {
                Node detailNode = N2.item(i);
                if (detailNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                    System.out.println("2------");
                    if (detailNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("image")) 
                    {
                        String sizeVal = ((Element) detailNode).getAttribute("size");
                        String url = detailNode.getTextContent();
                        if (sizeVal.equalsIgnoreCase("large")) {
                            return url;
                        }
                    }
                    }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The xml function which i call in the above code:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml;
}
```

getAlbumURL:

```
    public static String getAlbumURL(String artist, String album){
        return URL_METHOD + METHOD_GETALBUM + AMPERSAND
                + API_KEY + AMPERSAND
                + PARAM_ARTIST + artist + AMPERSAND
                + PARAM_ALBUM + album;
    }
```

XMLparser:

public class XMLParser {

```
// constructor
public XMLParser() {
}

//Get XML from URL
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xml;
}

//Get dom element
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

//Get nod element
 public final String getElementValue(Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

//Get element value
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
     NodeList nlList = item.getElementsByTagName(str).item(0).getChildNodes();
     Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
     return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }
```

}

Any ideas ? I seriously don't know what is wrong.. I used this before and it worked.

Comment: Please post how your xml looks like

Comment: Like this:
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=Radiohead&album=In%20raynbows

Comment: any errors? Can you debug and verify the string XML is valid XML is valid XML?

Comment: No errors, The URL is correct, when it reaches here:
String xml = xml_parser.getXmlFromUrl(getAlbumURL(artistName, albumName));
the app stops..

Comment: I tried to output the XML and nothing appears, but i am using that function in another class and it is working.
So the problem can only be in the first peace of code.

Comment: Okay. Let's see getAlbumUrl().

Comment: Edited main post.

It's pretty simple.
The returned url is correct i double tested it..

Comment: I'll have to take a look when I get access to Eclipse, if you haven't gotten an answer by then. In the meantime, I'd do a quick watch on each variable in that block and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: thanks ! i've been around this for a week... it must be something simple i am missing.

Comment: I'm not finding the type XMLParser. Eclipse recommends XMLPullParser, which is what I've used in the past. Where is that type coming from?

Comment: It's a custom class, check first post

Comment: I'll see if I can take another look at this over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled your code and tried it out. I redid the "getAlbumURL" to return a hardcoded string. I used the address you provided in the comments, it failed. However, that xml doesn't link to any album art. So I tried the proper album name, "In%20ra*i*nbows." Worked like a dream.

So first, verify that your constants are giving you what you think they should (which you already did) and second, verify your test data. Your code appears to be fine.

Comment: i wasn't testing with the example URL i gave you, i was using only one  word artists and albums, and it was outputting correct values.
I didn't change anything and it is working now.. i only added a method to add%20 to multiple word artists and albums.
No idea what i was missing.
thanks for you're time ! i really appreciate it ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Afte `DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();` add these lines before the `try{}` block:

```
dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
dbf.setCoalescing(true);
```